# How to open website's file directly?

Tags: url, iis, web, directory-browsing

If my title is not specific, let me explain. I want to open an asp.net website (locally in IIS 7). My problem is that I need to open the website's file which is located in two subfolders, and when i write the website's host name, I get the  of the website's folders.

If I disable Directory Browsing in IIS, I get this error:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Never mind I did it. Fro those who need help, I added the subfolder in HTTP Redirect Feature in IIS Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the file which you want to open as default document in IIS. Click on your website in IIS and then in the middle tab, browse to IIS section and open the default document tab and add your filename and move it to the top of the list.